# JFXtras - save added appoitment

Tags: java, javafx, calendar, jfxtras

I working on calendar with agenda so i use JFXtras library and there examples. And i need some help. Where i can save added appointment in JFXtras? I don't know anything about MySQL, is there any other option? Is it possible to do something with txt file, but how i can get info for exactly selected appointment?

```
Appointment[] lTestAppointments = new Appointment[]{
        new Agenda.AppointmentImplLocal()
            .withStartLocalDateTime(LocalDateTime.of(lTodayLocalDate, LocalTime.of(8, 00)))
            .withEndLocalDateTime(LocalDateTime.of(lTodayLocalDate, LocalTime.of(11, 30)))
            .withSummary("A")
            .withDescription("A much longer test description")
            .withAppointmentGroup(lAppointmentGroupMap.get("group07"))
    ..............................................................................
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JFXtras Agenda does one thing and one thing only: show the appointments you put in its appointments collection. It has absolutely no interest in how they got there or how they end up in some kind of database, that is totally up to you.
So if you add a button, and on click loop over the appointments in Agenda, and persist them in a txt file, then go ahead. It is your application.

Agenda has a selectedAppointments collections. But please read the javadoc? 
http://jfxtras.org/doc/8.0/jfxtras-agenda/jfxtras/scene/control/agenda/Agenda.html